# Jmeter - OpenJDK : java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.activation not found

Tags: java, windows, jar, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have

- Openjdk 12.0.2
- jmeter 4.0
- Windows 10

  When I am trying to launch Jmeter using "**jmeter.bat**" I am getting following error message :

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.activation not found
> errorlevel=1
> Press any key to continue . . .

I have gone through few blogs and answers which says I don't have "activation.jar". so now I have downloaded the required jar but don't have any idea regarding where to keep it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're suffering from [JMeter bug #62065](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62065)

As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter (which is [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) as of now) so consider upgrading JMeter to the latest stable version available from [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and you should be able to use it normally.

---

If for some reason you have to stay on JMeter 4.0 you can downgrade your Java to [OpenJDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

---

If for some reason you cannot do anything with the JMeter and OpenJDK version download [activation-1.1.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar) and drop it somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)